# Install Ubuntu 12.04 on laptop that won't recognize a USB or DVD

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 a 3-year old Samsung i3 which has a new hard drive.

For some reason, the laptop will not recognize a USB or DVD and I can't find a CD that will hold the 708MB file.

How can I install Ubuntu under these conditions?

Comment: Make sure the USB or DVD is created using the appropriate software and the ISO file is not corrupted.

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/340156/install-ubuntu-from-iso-image-directly-from-hard-disk-of-a-system-running-linux/340171#340171).

Answer (score 0):

if you cant repair the problem with usb or dvd, try a **minimal disk**(less than 100MB if I'm correct). write it on a cd and install all packages(such as ubuntu-desktop) by apt-get install .... however this way you should have a high speed Internet access on you desired laptop.