# I want to install Ubuntu [Any version greater than or equal to 12.04] from my windows OS

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows

I want to install Ubuntu [Any version greater than or equal to 12.04] from my windows OS ,
with no pendrive  and no CD.

Is it possible ?

By downloading an ISO , mount it to a drive and boot from there , to install ubuntu , along with my windows OS .

Comment: You could use WUBI

Comment: Does [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/340156/install-ubuntu-from-iso-image-directly-from-hard-disk-of-a-system-running-linux/340171#340171) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an Even Simpler way Try [WUBI](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) ..
Assuming you are using Windows 7, you can follow the steps mentioned in this guide.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows

Its actually quite simple.
1,this will automatically download the required ISO
2, create a temperoary folder inside windows partitions 
3, add entry in bootloader and start ubuntu installation on its own.

Hope this helps.