# Cannot Boot from CD or USB. Old Computer

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have an OLD system that I am trying to get back for an old customer. My problem is as follows:

MoBo only allows the system to boot from the CD Drive. Nothing else. Unfortunately, this drive will not read my DVD install disk for ubuntu.

I cannot put ubuntu on a CD because the .ISO is ~800 mb and the CD only holds 700.  So i cannot boot from USB, or DVD, and I cannot fit Ubuntu onto a CD.

How Can I put Ubuntu onto this HDD.  It is PATA.

Comment: Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/340156/install-ubuntu-from-iso-image-directly-from-hard-disk-of-a-system-running-linux/340171#340171

Answer (score -1):

I installed 11.10 onto cd as it just fits & then updated to 12.04 lts, this worked on my old Satellite pro. Its probably due to the chipset being non pae, as I found with mine 11.1 is the last to use a non pae bootloader