# Problem installing kubuntu from iso in hard disk drive

Tags: boot, grub2

I am trying to install Kubuntu 16.04 from hard drive and have followed the instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590863/grub-cannot-find-the-iso-image-on-the-hard-disk) and [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/196933/how-to-boot-linux-iso-images-directly-from-your-hard-drive/).

Well I have to remove the extension from both `vmlinuz` and `initrd`, I had some [question about the parameters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108106/grub-menu-linux-parameters-explained) but anyway it seems to work up to a point.

Unfortunately my process is stuck to a point where I get a message saying it could not find the ISO file. This seems strange enough since it clearly shows messages from the kernel. So, I guess it actually reads the files from the ISO file (where the previous file reside anyway). The actual message is this one (it's obviously a photo and not a clear one too):
[image: screenshot]

Acccording to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/741113/546065) my system is halted at the stage of mounting my root filesystem which in my case means the ISO file I guess.

The message:

> ...can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found

refers to my DVD drive and it's something like a bug (I have found some information about this one but lost the source to provide it here) I guess which I am not sure it has something to do with the actual problem here.

I have taken some action suggested elsewhere like booting into windows and using `shutdown /s` to have a clean windows system (although I am not sure I need a clean window system in this case anyway).

So, my questions are:

1. is why does this behaviour occur in the first place (why do I encounter a mount problem) since the `vmlinuz` and `initrd` seems to be found.
2. How do I proceed from here. Is there some option I can pass to read the actual ISO file for example?

My default system is an Kubuntu 14.04 32bit and I am trying to install a 64bit Kubuntu 16.04. My system is 64bit capable though since I also have 64bit win7 on it (dual boot).

If it helps the menunetry used in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` is:

```
menuentry "Kubuntu 16.04 ISO no ext" {
set isofile="kubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso"
loopback loop (hd0,6)/home/jorge/Torrents/$isofile
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${isofile} 
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}
```

and I don't have a separate `/home` partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the wrong path to your `.iso`-file in the `linux`-command:

```
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${isofile}
```

should be

```
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/home/jorge/Torrents/$isofile
```

You should also add the parameters `noprompt` and `noeject` to this line:

```
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/home/jorge/Torrents/$isofile noprompt noeject
```

to prevent being prompted to remove the installation media when the installation is finished and the machine is going to be rebooted.

Comment: You are right it did boot after the changes. As for the parameters as I said I asked but did not get any decent answer.

Comment: https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/live-boot-doc/live-boot.7.en.html http://www.clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live/boot-parameters/live-boot-contents-v2.php

Comment: That's the link I was looking for. An answer for 2 questions!