# How can I install system just from installed system, not USB or CD？

Tags: system-installation

I know how to create a bootable USB (pendrive), or CD, to install Ubuntu on to a hard disk. But I already had an installed system on USB, and **don't have any additional USB anymore**. So I booted into the system on USB already, how can I install a new Ubuntu system (or copy of my USB system) into the target hard disk?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Ubuntu from ISO image directly from hard disk of a system running Linux?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/340156/install-ubuntu-from-iso-image-directly-from-hard-disk-of-a-system-running-linux)

Answer (score 0):

There is [a method of installing anew from an ISO file without burning it to a disc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot):

1. Download an installer ISO. If you'll have a good Internet connection while installing, [mini.iso](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/xenial/) is an excellent option, giving a very small ISO file that can install any Ubuntu flavor.
2. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
3. Install `grml-rescueboot`:

   ```
   sudo apt install grml-rescueboot
   ```
4. Move the installer ISO you downloaded to `/boot/grml` (replace `filename.iso` with the actual ISO filename):

   ```
   sudo mv ~/Downloads/filename.iso /boot/grml/
   ```
5. Update GRUB:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
6. Reboot and select the ISO.
7. Install the desired flavor of Ubuntu, making sure to install it on the hard drive and not the USB drive.