# Can't boot from USB on HP Pavilion G6

Tags: boot, usb, xubuntu

I have a hp pavilion g6 series 32 bit , I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and everything was going fine until I downloaded bleachBit and I used this app incorrectly and it damaged my Ubuntu badly

I downloaded an ISO image for 32 bit Xubuntu and I have it now, but the problem is I have a 64gb sandisk usb I copied the iso image to the file and I have another file on the usb too, I tried to boot my laptop with usb but nothing appears; it keeps on starting normally.

I want to install this new iso image but I can't. Is there a way to install it without usb or cd?

Comment: See this:http://askubuntu.com/questions/340156/install-ubuntu-from-iso-image-directly-from-hard-disk-of-a-system-running-linux

Answer (score 0):

See this link and links from it for details about booting from USB,

[Installation/FromUSBStick#Booting_the_Computer_from_USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Booting_the_Computer_from_USB)

-o-

There are tools for installing an iso file into a USB drive in order to make it a USB boot drive with Ubuntu. But you should not have any other file on it, at least not when you make it a USB boot drive. So please copy the file(s) from the drive to some other drive, using another computer, if you have no working computer now.

**Cloned live-only system**

Do you intend to use this USB drive only during a short period of time in order to install Xubuntu into your computer? In this case I suggest that you make a *simple cloned system*. It is read-only and the drive cannot be used for anything else, but can be restored to a storage device afterwards.

In Ubuntu ('family' systems including Xubuntu) version 16.04 LTS and newer you can use the **Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator** *alias usb-creator-gtk*. In older Ubuntu versions you can use **Disks** alias *gnome-disks* or [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). *mkusb* can also restore the pendrive to a storage device afterwards, via the wipe menu.

In Windows you can use [**Win32 Disk Imager**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb) for the same purpose.

**Persistent live system**

If you wish to have a USB boot drive, that you want to tweak, and also use to store and transfer files, you can create a *persistent live drive*. mkusb can create such a drive too. See this link: [mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

Comment: Thank you for telling me that i have to transfer data on my usb to another computer to prevent loosing them... ill start with what you told me hopefully it will work thank you again

Comment: You are welcome and good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

May be the following steps will solve your problem

- As you have an another file in pen drive, you can't boot from it.

  - To make a working bootable pen drive visit any of the below links.
  - Also as you mentioned you are not able to use your laptop, use another person PC/Laptop to make pen drive bootable from it.
- Once you have a bootable pen drive you plug it and follow the procedure.

> Making a pen drive bootable

[Windows platform](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).

[Linux/Debian](https://unetbootin.github.io/).

> Installing Ubuntu

[Steps for installation of Ubuntu](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-Linux)

[Steps for installation of Xubuntu](https://www.lifewire.com/guide-to-installing-xubuntu-linux-2202075)