# How to reinstall ubuntu without changing boot order

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

Due to [funny bug with my laptop bios](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/3g64oa/samsung_series_7_laptop_unable_to_access_bios/) and UEFI: I can't change boot order and start Ubuntu installation from USB stick

But I want to reinstall my old Ubuntu. I'm not a guru of Linux and have few problems with system after many upgrades

As I understand, I can run installation:

- from [ISO file via Grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340156/install-ubuntu-from-iso-image-directly-from-hard-disk-of-a-system-running-linux)
- [manually setup Ubuntu parts](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/apds04.html) from old Ubuntu
- ???

What method is safer? I'm afraid, if I will break current installation I will not have second chance =(

As I wrote, I'm not a Linux guru, ubuntu-entrails manipulation scares me a little.

Comment: You generally don't have to change the boot order, just select boot device at startup, (usually f11, f12, or del)

Comment: @brndn2k no way. In boot menu (On Samsung F10) I see only current ubuntu option. It can be something related to Secure Boot