# Can I install Ubuntu directly to a hard drive?

Tags: system-installation

I just built a PC and I have 2 hard drives. I'm currently booting off the SSD with Windows, and I want to install Ubuntu on the other HDD. I downloaded the ISO, now what? Can I install it without having to burn it onto a cd/USB Flash Drive or anything else?

Comment: You need to "burn" the iso to some device you can boot from.

Comment: Well you  could put the iso in a partition and tell grub to boot from there but from an usb is so much easier...

Comment: You can install ubuntu directly from HDD, but you have to go through a lot of trouble for that. The easiest option would be to make a bootable usb device and install from it. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340156/install-ubuntu-from-iso-image-directly-from-hard-disk-of-a-system-running-linux) is a tutorial how to do that from HDD directly if you want to go the hard way.

Comment: @Pilot6 That question has no indication on how to do it without a USB.

Comment: You can use another HDD for that. It can be a SATA disk, not a USB. You can use your SSD for that, but it is quite difficult if you want to keep Windows there.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Using Grub to boot from an ISO image stored inside a file system assumes that there's a working Grub installation which doesn't appear to be the case if OP only has a Windows installation.