# install ubuntu directly onto partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

Installing ubuntu is always done by installing ubuntu first on some (USB/CD/something_else). And then booting from that thing. And then installing ubuntu on your pc from there. But if it's possible to install on a USB and also load it from there, then why cant I just install it on the partition directly.

Is it possible to just create a partition, then install ubuntu onto that partition from the OS that I'm currently using. And finally just modify UEFI/GRUB so that you can boot it.

And if so, are there any tools for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/340156/

Comment: Whilst it is possible to do what you’ve asked (see link above) having a usb/cd available can be useful if you ever hit problems such as a failure to boot. The usb/cd can be used to fix things. It’s also much easier to install from a usb/cd

Comment: No you misunderstand me. I want to skip the entire live environment. With the answer to the question linked above, they just do some trick so that you can load the live environment from a file. Then they boot the live environment and from there they do the installation.