# Usb os not booting

Tags: boot, live-usb, bios

Ubuntu, Black Arch,and Kali USB drives on USB all won't work since upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04. I've tried changing the BIOS setup utility in various ways and nothing seems to change.

Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong at getting the system to load USB flash drive first?

EDIT 1:
Ubuntu 18.04 was originally installed from the same USB drive that is not being recognised now.

Ubuntu 20.4 was the upgrade done via ubuntu update via web download.

Kali USB Stick is ISO file downloaded from kali.org.  Was  working on a laptop recently.

Black Arch seems to show as folder/files not an iso. Again worked on a laptop.

I suspect it's an issue in the BIOS setup as I've tried to vary the boot order of devices and the result is it always loads Ubuntu 20.04 from the SS HDD.

[image: eBoot Sequence 1]

[image: Boot sequence 2]

[CMOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K880W.jpg)

Comment: How the ISOs are written to thumb-drive really matters, as does the version of the software (*if a non-clone type of write is used*).  You're without any specifics; also mention Ubuntu Core 18 & Ubuntu Core 20 systems (most users use Ubuntu 18.04 or Ubuntu 20.04 and not the specialist year products; 18 & 18.04 being different Ubuntu systems*) so details matter.  Also this is a Q&A site (not a forum), but you've answered your own question I note, so we don't have to?  Your question is unclear, vague & without any screenshot(s).  Please provide clear Ubuntu ISO/release details

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  The Kali Linux & Black Arch details are off-topic here, this is a Ubuntu Q&A/support site; use SE *Unix & Linux* if you want help with Linux issues.. Also being precise matters, various 18.04 media exists using 4 kernel stacks, and various other differences including security changes; older media may no longer boot if your firmware was updated (thus the newer 18.04 media!)

Comment: eg. read https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/ and you'll note this media was created due to *boothole* vulnerability & that updated systems would no longer boot older 18.04 media (ie. not 18.04, 18.04.1, 18.04.2, 18.04.3, 18.04.4, or 18.04.5) thus the creation of the newer 18.04.6 media. For best help it's helpful if you're specific; as 18.04 can be used for all those media; also Desktop, Server & *flavor* ISOs exist too...  Same can apply with Ubuntu 20.04; ie. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ & new media created because of fixes

Answer (score 1):

Select the USB-HDD option of the boot sequence which is shown in the second screenshot of your question and then press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to save in order to boot from a bootable USB flash drive.

If that doesn't work try removing the CMOS battery coin for 5 minutes which sets the BIOS back to its default settings, and then reinserting it and change the boot priority settings to boot from the USB flash drive.

If your computer is still not cooperating there is an alternative way of booting an Ubuntu ISO without using a bootable USB stick. Please read the answers to [Install Ubuntu from ISO image directly from hard disk of a system running Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/q/340156/).

Comment: Thank you for this.  I have tried this already and it still boots Ubuntu 20.04 from the SS HDD.