Installing Kubuntu using partition (without pendrive)
In my laptop, windows 10 was not working at desired speed so i decided to install ubuntu, after some browsing i downloaded Kubuntu iso. I watched 2 tutorials about installing it without usb and both were same. After mounting iso on a partition with UUI, i restarted and option of try or install ubuntu appeared. At first, while installation, i couldn't see the bootloader option below that screen as shown in both videos i watched. So the installation failed. However i tried installing it several times and once it was completed and showed button of reboot now. When i rebooted, again it showed that try or install screen. And now i think my windows is also deleted in this process. If anyone can help, suggest me what to do?

What was the reason for not doing a normal USB boot media install?

You need to supply more details. (Assuming your are following something along the lines of https://askubuntu.com/questions/340156/install-ubuntu-from-iso-image-directly-from-hard-disk-of-a-system-running-linux you should still have a GRUB.) When you reboot do you get a grub menu? If you don't then SHIFT (BIOS) or ESC (UEFI) asserted during boot will get one. What options are shown? (Add details to your question.)
